# Lambda capturing this and long-running function

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, race-condition, undefined-behavior, weak-ptr

I have a function that takes a long time to run, but thankfully it runs asynchronously.  I want to take the result of this function call and set it to a class instance's private variable.  Seems easy:

```
// Exists in some other library.
void LongRunningAsync(std::function<void(int)> callback) {
  sleep(10);
  callback(5);
}

class A {
 public:
  void Do() {
    auto lambda = [this](int val) {
      // Some processing...
      var_ = val;
    };
    LongRunningAsync(lambda);
  }

 private:
  var_;
};

int main() {
  A* a = new A;
  a->Do();
  // Wait for LongRunningAsync to finish.
  sleep(20);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is adding the following line to `main`, right before the comment:

```
delete a;
```

Now when `LongRunningAsync` invokes the callback, it will attempt to modify a member variable of a deleted instance (which is UB).

Is there a way to salvage this approach? I've recently learned about the following solution:

```
void LongRunningAsync(std::function<void(int)> callback) {
  sleep(10);
  callback(5);
}

class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
 public:
  void Do() {
    std::weak_ptr<A> weak = shared_from_this();
    auto lambda = [weak](int val) {
      auto shared = weak.lock();
      if (!shared) return;
      // Some processing...
      shared->var_ = val;
    };
    LongRunningAsync(lambda);
  }

 private:
  var_;
};

int main() {
  auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
  a->Do();
  // Wait for LongRunningAsync to finish.
  sleep(20);
  return 0;
}
```

But it requires changing **all** `A` variables to shared_ptr.  Is there a less intrusive way to make this work?

Comment: Maybe you can make the class `A` hold a `shared_ptr` that contains all the state needed?

Comment: You should not synchronize with `sleep` but by `thread::join` or similar.

Comment: Well, first of all, do you really have to use that library?
The interface of this "Long-running asynchronous function" looks quite clumsy to me. I would expect async function to return `std::future` and let the client decide when to fetch the result rather than invoke a callback.
Secondly, I assume that in your example `sleep(10); callback(5);` should be invoked in a separate thread, because currently the call to LongRunningAsync will actually block the execution.

Comment: @Curious: That's actually a really good idea! let me try it...

Comment: @Jarod42: This is just an example.

Comment: @VasiliyGalkin: Yes, the function runs on a separate thread. And unfortunately, yes, I do need to use this library (it is rather old, and does things the older way...)

Comment: @Curious: That solution does indeed work; can you post an answer and I'll reward you? :)

Comment: @SteveD posted 

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to just encapsulate the state you need into a `shared_ptr` member variable and then capture that by value into the closure that runs asynchronously.

Something like the following

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
  void Do() {
    auto lambda = [member_shared_state](int val) {
      member_shared_state->var_ = val;
    };
    LongRunningAsync(lambda);
  }
  ....
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on Curious's approach, but that doesn't force me to change all pointers to `A` objects to `shared_ptr`:

```
// Exists in some other library.
void LongRunningAsync(std::function<void(int)> callback) {
  sleep(10);
  callback(5);
}

class A {
 public:
  A() : var_(std::make_shared<int>()) {}
  void Do() {
    std::weak_ptr<int> weak = var_;
    auto lambda = [weak](int val) {
      auto shared = weak.lock();
      if (!shared) {
        return;
      }
      // Some processing...
      *shared = val;
    };
    LongRunningAsync(lambda);
  }

 private:
  std::shared_ptr<int> var_;
};

int main() {
  A* a = new A;
  a->Do();
  delete a;
  // Wait for LongRunningAsync to finish.
  sleep(20);
  return 0;
}
```